# É correto salvar várias entidades ao mesmo tempo no Controller ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Necessito salvar 12 entidades ao no mesmo método, no *Controller*,  não sei se estou fazendo da forma correta.

Em meu método `Create` do *Controller*, chamo todas as entidade e adiciono todos os atributos na mesma *View*. Ao clicar no botão salvar, está salvando normalmente. Gostaria de saber se esta é a forma correta? Se não for, gostaria de saber qual a melhor.

Lembrando que este é apenas uma aplicação simples, onde não conterá muitas informações. Será usada apenas para não precisar digitalizar novos formulários.

Minha Action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Animal animal, Atividade atividade, Comunicacao comunicacao, Educacao educacao,
     Especie especie, EstruturaPropriedade estruturaPropriedade, Informacao informacao, Poco poco, ProdutorRural produtorRural,
    Propriedade propriedade, Questionario questionario, Saude saude)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Animais.Add(animal);
        db.Atividades.Add(atividade);
        db.Comunicacoes.Add(comunicacao);
        db.Educacoes.Add(educacao);
        db.Especies.Add(especie);
        db.EstruturaPropriedades.Add(estruturaPropriedade);
        db.Infomacoes.Add(informacao);
        db.Pocos.Add(poco);
        db.ProdutorRurals.Add(produtorRural);   
        db.Propriedades.Add(propriedade);
        db.Questionarios.Add(questionario);
        db.Saudes.Add(saude);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(propriedade);
}
```

E na *View*, eu chamo os atributos através das *foreign key*.
Não irei postar todo o código, pois são 213 atributos, e ficaria de difícil entendimento, pelo tamanho do código, mas colocarei uma parte.

Entidade:

```
public class Propriedade
    {
        [Key]
        public int iPropriedadeID { set; get; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite o nome do Proprietário")]
        public string sProprietario { get; set; }
        public string sSexo { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? dtNasc { get; set; }
        public string sTelefone { get; set; }
        public string sCelular { get; set; }
        public string sEndereco { get; set; }
        public int? iRg { get; set; }
        public string sUfrg { get; set; }
        public string sCpf { get; set; }
        public string sCpts { get; set; }
        public string sSerieCtps { get; set; }
        public string sNomePropriedade { get; set; }
        public int? iInscricaoMunicipal { get; set; }
        public bool bRegPropriedade { get; set; }
        public string sCartorio { get; set; }
        public string sMtricula { get; set; }
        public string sLivro { get; set; }
        public int? iArea { get; set; }
        public int? iAreaRegistrada { get; set; }
        public int? iAreaTotal { get; set; }
        public bool bIncra { get; set; }
        public string sNumIncra { get; set; }
        public string sNirf { get; set; }
        public string sInscricaoImobiliaria { get; set; }
        public string sDistrito { get; set; }
        public int? iTempoOcupacao { get; set; }
        public string sLocalX { get; set; }
        public string sLocalY { get; set; }

        public virtual ProdutorRural ProdutorRural { get; set; }
        public virtual Animal Animal{ get; set; }
        public virtual Atividade Atividade { get; set; }
        public virtual EstruturaPropriedade EstruturaPropriedade  { get; set; }
```

A *View* para salvar possui 2300 linhas, então postarei o início, e sigo esta mesa base até o final:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                Nome do Proprietário:
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sProprietario, new {@class = "form-control", style = "width:5000px", placeholder = "Nome Completo"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        @*-------------------------------------------------------LINHA 2-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*@

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                Sexo:
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sSexo, new SelectList(
                    new[]
                    {
                        new {Value = "Masculino", Text = "Masculino"},
                        new {Value = "Feminino", Text = "Feminino"},
                    },
                    "Value",
                    "Text"
                    ), new {@class = "form-control", style = "width: 150px;"})
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                Data de Nascimento:
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dtNasc, new { placeholder = "Ex: 20/02/2014"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dtNasc)
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Existem "n" formas melhores de fazer, afetando muito a sua implementação. Por isso não sei se essa seria uma boa pergunta. Ela é complexa/abrangente e difícil de ser respondida, e provavelmente acabará/acabaria sendo debatida.

Comment: @Renan, Especificando um pouco mais, eu terei algum problema futuro com esta forma?

Comment: Se você colocar duas formas de fazer essa inserção na sua pergunta e você perguntar qual dessas duas formas eh mais recomentada/melhor, fica mais fácil de responder. Porém da forma que está, muitas pessoas responderiam, de várias formas e provavelmente não teria uma resposta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vou basear minha resposta não mencionando uma maneira correta, e sim uma maneira *performática* de como fazer isso.

Vejo isto com severa preocupação:

```
public ActionResult Create(Animal animal, Atividade atividade, Comunicacao comunicacao, Educacao educacao,
     Especie especie, EstruturaPropriedade estruturaPropriedade, Informacao informacao, Poco poco, ProdutorRural produtorRural,
    Propriedade propriedade, Questionario questionario, Saude saude) { ... }
```

Não que esteja errado, mas isso torna a manutenção absurdamente difícil, visto que o programador vai ter que ir descobrindo como funciona o *binding* completo do formulário.

A maneira performática de fazer isso é especificando um *ViewModel* que contenha todas as propriedades que são entidades:

```
public class FormularioViewModel 
{
    public Animal Animal { get; set; }
    public Atividade Atividade { get; set; }
    public Comunicacao Comunicacao { get; set; }
    public Educacao Educacao { get; set; }
    public Especie Especie { get; set; }
    public EstruturaPropriedade EstruturaPropriedade { get; set; }
    public Informacao Informacao { get; set; }
    public Poco Poco { get; set; }
    public ProdutorRural ProdutorRural { get; set; }
    public Propriedade Propriedade { get; set; }
    public Questionario Questionario { get; set; }
    public Saude Saude { get; set; }
}
```

*ViewModels* não são persistidos. São apenas classes anêmicas usadas para organizar e validar seu formulário. *ViewModels*, quando implementam [`IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx), se comportam de maneira idêntica a um *Model*, inclusive atualizando o `ModelState` do *Controller*.

Com isso, o cabeçalho da *Action* do seu *Controller* ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(FormularioViewModel viewModel) { ... }
```

E a *View*:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Nome do Proprietário:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Animal.Proprietario, new {@class = "form-control", style = "width:5000px", placeholder = "Nome Completo"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    @*-------------------------------------------------------LINHA 2-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*@

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Sexo:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Animal.Sexo, new SelectList(
                new[]
                {
                    new {Value = "Masculino", Text = "Masculino"},
                    new {Value = "Feminino", Text = "Feminino"},
                },
                "Value",
                "Text"
                ), new {@class = "form-control", style = "width: 150px;"})
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Data de Nascimento:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Animal.DataNascimento, new { placeholder = "Ex: 20/02/2014"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Animal.DataNascimento)
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

A *Action* de persistir dados ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Animais.Add(viewModel.Animal);
    db.Atividades.Add(viewModel.Atividade);
    db.Comunicacoes.Add(viewModel.Comunicacao);
    db.Educacoes.Add(viewModel.Educacao);
    db.Especies.Add(viewModel.Especie);
    db.EstruturaPropriedades.Add(viewModel.EstruturaPropriedade);
    db.Infomacoes.Add(viewModel.Informacao);
    db.Pocos.Add(viewModel.Poco);
    db.ProdutorRurals.Add(viewModel.ProdutorRural);   
    db.Propriedades.Add(viewModel.Propriedade);
    db.Questionarios.Add(viewModel.Questionario);
    db.Saudes.Add(viewModel.Saude);

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

return View(propriedade);
```

Além disso, usando esta abordagem, você pode segmentar sua *View* em *Partials*, mais ou menos assim:

```
@Html.Partial("_Animal", Model.Animal)
@Html.Partial("_Atividade", Model.Atividade)
@Html.Partial("_Comunicacao", Model.Comunicacao)
...
```

Assim ela não teria 2300 linhas.

Comment: a parte de colocar minha View em Partials eu estava elaborando ontem a noite. Já o ViewModel para esta finalidade eu não havia visto ainda. Irei implementar hoje. Obrigado pela ajuda