# Como funciona o ViewModel no asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho uma situação parecida com [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48337/%C3%89-correto-salvar-v%C3%A1rias-entidades-ao-mesmo-tempo-no-controller-asp-net-mvc) onde preciso salvar vários *models* de uma vez só e relacionar cada um. Eu precisaria meio que salvar em cascata para primeiro salvar uma entidade e depois ir salvando as outras, por causa dos relacionamentos.

Seguindo a pergunta, criei um *ViewModel* com todas as tabelas que seriam salvas de uma vez, como no código abaixo:

```
public class AnamineseViewModel
{
    //
    //porque dessa forma ficaria mais fácil de salvar tudo relacionado a anaminese
    #region Mapeamento dos objetos

    public CliCliente CliCliente { get; set; }
    public Tabela2 Tabela2 { get; set; }
    public Tabela3 Tabela3 { get; set; }
    public Tabela4 Tabela4 { get; set; }
    public Tabela5 Tabela5 { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

A minha dúvida é: como posso criar um *controller* e *views* para essa *ViewModel*?

Lembrando que primeiro devo cadastrar o cliente, após devo conseguir relacionar a `tabela2`, depois que salvar a `tabela2` relacionar ela ao resto e conseguir salvar tudo no banco e editar e listar e tudo mais...

Teria como?

## EDIT

Os relacionamento que tenho são:

- Tabela2 com CliCliente, Tabela3, Tabela4 e Tabela5;
- Tabela3 com Tabela2
- Tabela4 com Tabela2
- Tabela5 com Tabela2

**Todos eles sendo de 1:1.**

Comment: Poderia adicionar o seus modelos reais? As vezes o que você procura nem precisa ser por ViewModel.

Comment: @Randrade mas teria como fazer sem ser por ViewModel? São 5 entidades...

Comment: Se são entidades relacionadas (de preferência 1:1), você não precisa de ViewModel, e sim o relacionamento das mesmas.

Comment: Mesmo que eu precise salvar tudo de uma vez? @Randrade

Comment: Sim. Por exemplo: Se você estiver salvando um **Cliente**, onde esse cliente possui um **Endereco**, um **Usuario**, etc.. Você está salvando um **Cliente**, e dele você consegue todos esses valores. Geralmente, é utilizado `ViewModel` somente quando o seu `Model` não atende a todas as necessidades.

Comment: Se você observar, na pergunta que linkou (é de minha autoria, e tinha vergonha dela, mas parece estar ajudando mais pessoas) nem todos os Models possuem relação direta, por isso uma `ViewModel` é a melhor opção.

Comment: Não tenha vergonha dela não @Randrade.. Foi ela que me ajudou na minha solução! kkkk. Mas eu entendi a ideia, muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu disse que "tinha", pois não sabia que ela havia ajudado mais alguém. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faça um *Controller* vazio. Minha sugestão:

```
public class AnaminasesController : Controller
{
    protected SeuContexto contexto = new SeuContexto();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        /* Liste aqui o que pode ser interessante entre todos os Models envolvidos */
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new AnamineseViewModel 
        {
            CliCliente = new CliCliente(),
            Tabela2 = new Tabela2(),
            Tabela3 = new Tabela3(),
            Tabela4 = new Tabela4(),
            Tabela5 = new Tabela5(),
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AnamineseViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            /* Salve todas as informações aqui */

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    /* Os demais métodos seguem a mesma lógica. */
}
```

Como na pergunta mencionada, gere Partials para cada entidade a ser criada ou editada. Minha sugestão para *Create*:

```
@model SeuProjeto.ViewModel.AnaminaseViewModel

@using Html.BeginForm() 
{
    @Html.Partial("_Cliente", Model.CliCliente)
    @Html.Partial("_Tabela2", Model.Tabela2)
    @Html.Partial("_Tabela3", Model.Tabela3)
    @Html.Partial("_Tabela4", Model.Tabela4)
    @Html.Partial("_Tabela5", Model.Tabela5)
}
```

Para deixar essa criação de *Partials* mais dinâmica, faça *Scaffold* de todas as entidades e aproveite o código delas.

---

Como você complementou a resposta, preciso fazer alguns adendos.

- Se `CliCliente` se relaciona com `Tabela2` e `Tabela3`, `Tabela4` e `Tabela5` também, o relacionamento entre `CliCliente` e `Tabela2` pode ser descartado. Veja que falei "pode", não que "deve";
- [Como o @Randrade pontuou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130770/como-funciona-o-viewmodel-no-asp-net-mvc/130773#comment272601_130770), se você tem a cadeia de relacionamentos, você não precisa usar o *ViewModel*, porque:

### 1. Sua *Action* `Edit` já carrega tudo pra você

Ou seja:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var cliente = db.CliClientes
                    .Include(c => c.Tabela2)
                    .Include(c => c.Tabela3)
                    .Include(c => c.Tabela4)
                    .Include(c => c.Tabela5)
                    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CliClienteId == id);

    return View();
}
```

### 2. Sua *Action* `Create` pode usar um `CliCliente` vazio ao invés de um *ViewModel*

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new CliCliente 
    {
        Cliente2 = new Cliente2(),
        Cliente3 = new Cliente3(),
        Cliente4 = new Cliente4(),
        Cliente5 = new Cliente5(),
    });
}
```

### 3. As *Actions* de `POST` podem receber diretamente seu *Model*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CliCliente cliente) { ... }
```

Mas cuidado com isso. Procure usar o atributo [`[Bind]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) para limitar os campos que o *binder* irá aceitar.

Comment: òtima resposta Cigano! Tenho uma dúvida... Como que eu poderia fazer para mostrar o que eu queria na Index? Pois fica meio complicado mostrar pelo fato de ter muitos models... Teria como colocar na sua resposta? E outra, como que eu poderia salvar essas informações no Create?

Comment: Para eu fazer isso, preciso entender as relações entre as entidades. Para salvar as informações, deve ter uma entidade que é relacionada com todas as outras. Basta adicionar esta entidade usando um `context.Entidades.Add(entidade);` que o EF faz o resto.

Comment: Quer que eu coloque no texto da minha pegunta os meus models? Pode ficar grande demais a pergunta... Mas se quiser eu coloco... Ou eu poderia colocar como são os relacionamentos, pode ser?

Comment: coloquei os relacionamentos!

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Vou complementar a resposta. Confira pra ver se não haverá dúvidas.

Comment: Entendi Cigano!Mas acho que com ViewModel ficaria mais fácil de entender e dar manutenção... Pelo menos pra mim... Porque o que acontece é que A tabela2 é que se relaciona com todas as outras... Ficou mais fácil pra mim, criar um view model e cadastrar tudo de uma vez, do que passar no binder... São muitos campos que eu teria que passar, seria muito complicado, até porque todos os dados tenho que salvar no banco...

Comment: Bom, aí é com você. O objetivo é mostrar as possibilidades. Bom desenvolvimento ;)

Comment: Cara, deu erro quando fui cadastrar tudo.. =(. Vou fazer outra pergunta, será que poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Sim. Seja mais específico nesta próxima.

Comment: [Aqui a minha pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131066/erro-cadastrar-dados-na-viewmodel)

Answer (score 4):

Para criar o *controller* e as *view* correspondente a um determinado *ViewModel* faça:

**ViewModel**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class ExampleViewModel
    {
        public Produto Produto { get; set; }
        public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }

    public class Produto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cliente
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Nessa *ViewModel* (`ExampleViewModel`) eu tenho duas agregações das classes `Produto` e `Cliente` e com elas vou criar as *view* Principal (`Create`) e suas respectivas views para cada agregação existente.

***Como seria?***

```
public class ExamplesController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet()]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost()]
    public ActionResult Create(ExampleViewModel exampleViewModel)
    {
        //ROTINAS DE GRAVAÇÃO
        return View();
    }
}
```

No `controller` é simples crie um Create com o `verb GET` e outro com o `verb POST` com um parametro do seu `ViewModel` (`ExampleViewModel`).

*Crie a sua view nesse formato:*

***View Produto: (_Produto.cshtml)***

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.ExampleViewModel
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Produto</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Produto.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Produto.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Produto.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Produto.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***View Cliente: (_Cliente.cshtml)***

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.ExampleViewModel
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Cliente</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cliente.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cliente.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cliente.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cliente.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cliente.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cliente.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Observe que essas duas *views* que são complemento de suas *view* Principal tem um fator interessante que eu coloque o seu tipo no `@model` a sua ViewModel `ExampleViewModel`, porque?

Para que o `binding`(*as informações passadas nos campos seja carregados em sua classe de maneira simples e transparente*) funcione corretamente, ou seja, para que ao mandar as informações para `Create` (`do verb POST`) ele carregue a classe corretamente. Olha a nomenclatura de um item:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cliente.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Ele foi montado em cima de sua agregação demonstrado ai em `model.Cliente.Id`, para que ele dê o `binding` corretamente das informações.

***View Principal: (Create.cshtml)***

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.ExampleViewModel
@{ Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")    

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        @Html.Partial("_Cliente", Model)
        <hr />
        @Html.Partial("_Produto", Model)

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>ExampleViewModel</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

***Html gerada***

```
<form action="/Examples/Create" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="Mr207UcvrXamhyWWVqGbKBVZ8wY9ccJoBqcGVCjwg3G_tjHWIymMjfzE5o1XkXaJ8Q0WsL5XWMhq3biQfh7rKmuerIMuMPCgPFEOzA7baNc1" /><div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Cliente</h4>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Cliente_Id">Id</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="O campo Id é obrigatório." id="Cliente_Id" name="Cliente.Id" type="number" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Cliente.Id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Cliente_Nome">Nome</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Cliente_Nome" name="Cliente.Nome" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Cliente.Nome" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>        <hr />
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Produto</h4>
    <hr />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Produto_Id">Id</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="O campo Id é obrigatório." id="Produto_Id" name="Produto.Id" type="number" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Produto.Id" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Produto_Descricao">Descricao</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Produto_Descricao" name="Produto.Descricao" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Produto.Descricao" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>ExampleViewModel</h4>
            <hr />

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Nessa geração é fácil ver porque as agregações da classe `ExampleViewModel` são carregadas, os campos por exemplo nome do cliente em sua `tag input` do tipo `text` tem o nome `Cliente.Nome`. Cliente é a `classe` e o Nome sua *propriedade*, é assim que o ***MVC*** consegue definir as informações e carregar nas classes correspondente.

*Se você montar diferente não vai funcionar !!!*

Comment: Na montagem dos models é necessário mesmo que fique tudo em um model só? Porque da forma que fiz, fiz cada model em uma classe diferente e uma outra classe, que é a mostrada acima na pergunta, juntando todas... É necessário que esteja dessa forma mesmo?

Comment: Os models são únicos e sozinhos, já o ViewModel possui esses models. É o que você disse, acredito que você esteja fazendo alguma confusão leia com calma e me pergunte novamente!

Comment: Só uma correção: "parse" no ASP.NET MVC é conhecido como *binding*. Parse é outra coisa. O resto está ok.

Comment: Sim foi um lapso da minha parte eu realmente também sei a diferença. Obrigado @cigano

Comment: Cara, valeu demais! A sua resposta e a do Cigano se complementam, pra mim né? Muito bom! Obrigado! Agora entendi a ideia!