# Erro cadastrar dados na ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130770/como-funciona-o-viewmodel-no-asp-net-mvc/) onde onde fiz de acordo com as repostas, minha lógica... Só que agora, ao cadastrar os dados, um erro foi gerado. Esse erro se refere a propriedade de uma view que não pode ser nula, que é o ID. Ou seja, pelo que entendi, os dados não foram cadastrados, e por algum motivo isso ocorreu não gerando nenhum registro na tabela, ou não está reconhecendo a lógica...

Bem, o meu controller esta dessa forma:

```
 // GET: Controller/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new AnamineseViewModel
        {
            CliCliente = new CliCliente(),
            Tabela2= new Tabela2(),
            Tabela3 = new Tabela3(),
            Tabela4 = new Tabela4(),
            Tabela5 = new Tabela5(),
        });
    }

    // POST: Controller/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AnamineseViewModel anaminese)
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.CliCliente.Add(anaminese.CliCliente);
            db.Tabela2.Add(anaminese.Tabela2);
            db.Tabela3.Add(anaminese.Tabela3);
            db.Tabela4.Add(anaminese.Tabela4);
            db.Tabela5.Add(anaminese.Tabela5);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(anaminese);
    }
```

Tem alguma coisa errada com isso?

## EDIT

A view correspondente:

```
@model MeuProjeto.Models.AnamineseViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<h2>Create</h2>

@Html.Partial("_PartialCliente", Model.CliCliente)
@Html.Partial("_PartialTabela2", Model.Tabela2)
@Html.Partial("_PartialTabela3", Model.Tabela3)
@Html.Partial("_PartialTabela4", Model.Tabela4)
@Html.Partial("_PartialTabela5", Model.Tabela5)

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>

}
```

## Tabela2

```
@model NutriSport.Models.AnaAnamineseAlimentar

@*@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>AnaAnamineseAlimentar</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaObjetivosMetas, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnaObjetivosMetas, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaObjetivosMetas, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaRotina, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnaRotina, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaRotina, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaDisposicao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnaDisposicao)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaDisposicao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaComorbidades, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnaComorbidades, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaComorbidades, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaResfriado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnaResfriado)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaResfriado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaMedicamentos, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnaMedicamentos, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaMedicamentos, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaConsumoAgua, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnaConsumoAgua, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaConsumoAgua, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CliId, "CliId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.Hidden("CliId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CliId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RecId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RefId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RefId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QfaId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QfaId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QfaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>*@
</div>
@*  }*@

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

## CliCLiente

```
@model NutriSport.Models.CliCliente

@*@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>CliCliente</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CliNome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CliNome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CliNome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CliDataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CliDataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CliDataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CliEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CliEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CliEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CliSexo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CliSexo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CliSexo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CliCidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CliCidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CliCidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CliTelefone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CliTelefone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CliTelefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CliCelular, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CliCelular, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CliCelular, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CliOcupacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CliOcupacao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CliOcupacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>*@
</div>
@* }*@

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

## Tabela3

```
@model NutriSport.Models.RecRecordatorio

@*@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>RecRecordatorio</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecId, "RecId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Hidden("RecId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecHoraDorme, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecHoraDorme, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecHoraDorme, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecHoraAcorda, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RecHoraAcorda, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecHoraAcorda, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AnaId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>*@
</div>
@*  }*@

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

## Tabela4

```
@model NutriSport.Models.RefRefeicao

@*@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>RefRefeicao</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefId, "RefId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Hidden("RefId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RefId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefTipo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RefTipo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RefTipo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefHorarioLocal, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RefHorarioLocal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RefHorarioLocal, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RefAlimentosQuantidades, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RefAlimentosQuantidades, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RefAlimentosQuantidades, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AnaId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>*@
</div>
@*  }*@

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

## Tabela5

```
@model NutriSport.Models.QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar

@*@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>QfaQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QfaId, "QfaId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.Hidden("QfaId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QfaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QfaGrupoAlimentar, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QfaGrupoAlimentar, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QfaGrupoAlimentar, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QfaDia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QfaDia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QfaDia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QfaSemana, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QfaSemana, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QfaSemana, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QfaMes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QfaMes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QfaMes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QfaNunca, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QfaNunca)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QfaNunca, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QfaRaramente, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QfaRaramente)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QfaRaramente, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QfaObservacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QfaObservacao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QfaObservacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AnaId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>*@
</div>
@*  }*@

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Valor não pode ser nulo. No trecho db.CliCliente.Add(anaminese.Cliente)

Comment: Poste na sua pergunta como estão suas *Views*, por favor.

Comment: As *Partials* também.

Comment: São bem grandes... Tem algum problema?

Comment: Não. Problema não tem.

Comment: Coloquei as partials

Comment: @João entendi sim... Só que nos campos de Id não preciso que sejam editorfor... O editorfor irá criar um campo de texto, isso pode confundir o usuário e induzi-lo a preencher esse campo, já que não é para preencher.... E eu tentei tipo as view com o meu ViewModel, só que eles não conseguem acessa-lo... Mas vou tentar aqui pra ver!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas aí. Como todas as relações são de N para 1 (e não de 1 para N), as *Partials* terão que ser chamadas assim:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialCliente", Model)
@Html.Partial("_PartialTabela2", Model)
@Html.Partial("_PartialTabela3", Model)
@Html.Partial("_PartialTabela4", Model)
@Html.Partial("_PartialTabela5", Model)
```

Isto porque, ao criar os campos do formulário, o *Helper* não especifica de qual entidade o campo vem. Por exemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AnaRotina, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnaRotina, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AnaRotina, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Vai criar:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="AnaRotina">Rotina</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" name="AnaRotina" id="AnaRotina" class="form-control" />
        <span ... />
    </div>
</div>
```

O certo seria:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Tabela2.AnaRotina">Rotina</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" name="Tabela2.AnaRotina" id="Tabela2_AnaRotina" class="form-control" />
        <span ... />
    </div>
</div>
```

Então temos que mudar `@model` de todas as *Partials* para:

```
@model MeuProjeto.Models.AnamineseViewModel
```

E os campos:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tabela2.AnaRotina, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tabela2.AnaRotina, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tabela2.AnaRotina, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Outra coisa é que você está criando `@Html.BeginForm` em todas as *Partials*. Isto está errado. `@Html.BeginForm` fica na *View* principal (o que já está feito corretamente). Apague os `@Html.BeginForm` das *Partials*.

Comment: Mas eu tentei dessa forma, só que a View não consegue mudar e acessar dessa forma... Mas vou tentar aqui então!

Comment: Outra coisa, com relação aos campos de Id, eles são necessários? Ou seja, quando criei o scaffolding, campos do tipo dropdown foram criados e referentes aos Ids... Eles são necessários nas views?

Comment: Cara deu certo! Mas agora estou tendo um outro problema.. Ao salvar no banco, alguns relacionamentos não estão sendo respeitados e salvos no banco.... Fiz até [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131105/relacionamentos-n%C3%A3o-salvos).