# Relacionamentos não salvos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados

Tenho [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131066/erro-cadastrar-dados-na-viewmodel/131069#131069) onde graças a ajuda dos colegas eu consegui resolver a minha situação. Bem, pelo menos em partes... Após fazer os ajustes apontados, os dados estão sendo salvos. Mas os relacionamentos não estão sendo salvos durante o cadastramento dos dados.

Para deixar claro, faço os relacionamentos entre várias tabelas, em que o relacionamento é 1:1 entre cada tabela...

Vamos lá:

- Tenho a Tabela2 que se relaciona com CliCliente. Tabela2 que se relaciona com a Tabela3. Tabela2 que se relaciona com a Tabela4 e Tabela 2 que relaciona com a Tabela5.
- Tenho a Tabela3 que relaciona com a Tabela2.
- Tenho a Tabela4 que se relaciona com a Tabela2.
- Tenho a Tabela5 que se relaciona com a Tabela2.

Ok, entendido como funciona os relacionamentos, fiz o que esta descrito na pergunta. Fiz o ViewModel, tudo certinho. Beleza.

O cadastramento dos dados está tranquilo, mas quando é para relacionar as tabelas, esse relacionamento não está sendo salvo no banco. O unico relacionamento que é salvo no banco é entre Tabela2 e CliCliente.

Para ficar mais claro, vou postar aqui as imagens que tenho.

## Tabela2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Tabela3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Tabela4

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Tabela5

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verifiquei tudo e esta da forma como deveria estar, mas os relacionamentos não estão sendo salvos... Alguém sabe o porque disso estar ocorrendo?

## EDIT

O meu controller do ViewModel:

```
 // GET: Anaminese/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new AnamineseViewModel
        {
            CliCliente = new CliCliente(),
            Tabela2 = new Tabela2(),
            Tabela3 = new Tabela3(),
            Tabela4 = new Tabela4(),
            Tabela5 = new Tabela5(),
        });
    }

    // POST: Anaminese/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(AnamineseViewModel anaminese)
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Tabela2 tabela2 = anaminese.Tabela2;
            Tabela3 tabela3 = anaminese.Tabela3;
            Tabela4 tabela4 = anaminese.Tabela4;
            Tabela5 tabela5 = anaminese.Tabela5;

            Tabela3.Tabela2 = tabela2;
            Tabela4.Tabela2 = tablea2;
            Tabela5.Tabela2 = tabela2;

            db.CliCliente.Add(anaminese.CliCliente);
            db.Tabela2.Add(anaminese.Tabela2);
            db.Tabela3.Add(tabela3);
            db.Tabela4.Add(tabela4);
            db.Tabela5.Add(tabela5);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "UsuUsuario");
        }

        return View(anaminese);
    }
```

O meu DbContext

```
  public DbSet<UsuUsuario> UsuUsuario { get; set; }

    //Criando no banco a tabela de perfil com seus campos
    public DbSet<PerPerfil> PerPerfil { get; set; }

    //Criando no banco a tabela de perfil com seus campos
    public DbSet<CliCliente> CliCliente { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Tabela2> Tabela2 { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Tabela3> Tabela3{ get; set; }

    public DbSet<Tabela4> Tabela4 { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Tabela5> Tabela5 { get; set; }

    //Atualizando o contexto sempre com o que há de mais novo
    //dessa forma o banco estara sempre atualizado
    public EntidadesContexto()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<EntidadesContexto, Configuration>());
    }
```

Comment: O relacionamento são todos 1 para 1?

Comment: Isso @João. São todos de um para por conta da necessidade do projeto mesmo...

Comment: Perfeito, era uma duvida minha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com as respostas anteriores e nessa pergunta dizendo que a `tabela2` se relaciona com as `tabela3`, `tabela4` e `tabela5` esse código não reflete a gravação dos relacionamentos realmente. Acredito ser um `EntityFramework` o `ORM` utilizado, por causa do comando `SaveChanges` [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131066/46523).

*O código seria assim na hora que você inserir:*

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AnamineseViewModel anaminese)
{
    // TODO: Add insert logic here
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        CliCliente cliente = anaminese.CliCliente

        Tabela2 tabela2 = anaminese.Tabela2;

        cliente.Tabela2 = tabela2;  

        Tabela3 tabela3 = anaminese.Tabela3;
        Tabela4 tabela4 = anaminese.Tabela4;
        Tabela5 tabela5 = anaminese.Tabela4;

        tabela3.Tabela2 = tabela2;
        tabela4.Tabela2 = tabela2;
        tabela5.Tabela2 = tabela2;

        db.CliCliente.Add(cliCliente);      
        db.Tabela2.Add(tabela2);        
        db.Tabela3.Add(tabela3);        
        db.Tabela4.Add(tabela4);        
        db.Tabela5.Add(tabela5);        

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(anaminese);
}
```

Se os relacionamentos estiverem corretos isso vai funcionar.

Comment: Cara, não funcionou... =(

Comment: Qual é/são os erros ? Coloque todas as classes desse projeto na sua pergunta bem organizado

Comment: Não mostra erro... Salva tudo direitinho, mas não salva os IDs, igual o que acontece nas imagens. =(. Quais classes você quer?

Comment: Bom, eu preciso ver os códigos dessa classe + a classe que configura ou DbContext, se puder e quiser cole organizado todas as classes!

Comment: Voce fala o meu controller do viewmodel e o DbContext?

Comment: sim tudo tabelas etc etc etc

Comment: Meus Models são grandes, melhor ir pro chat não?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40462/discussion-between-joao-and-erik-thiago).

Answer (score 2):

A lógica não vai funcionar do jeito que está porque você não está necessariamente criando elementos de `Tabela2`, `Tabela3`, `Tabela4` e `Tabela5` em toda criação de `CliCliente`. Mas se eles não existem ainda assim, isto aqui já resolveria o problema:

```
db.CliCliente.Add(cliCliente);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Isto porque, a partir do Entity Framework 6, o framework é inteligente o suficiente para detectar as dependências entre suas entidades. Portanto, você não precisaria adicionar todos manualmente.

Ainda assim, se você quer fazer desta forma, é possível, mas o resultado é um pouco mais complexo e dá um pouco mais de trabalho.

Primeiro, adicione ao seu projeto o Assembly `System.Transactions`, se já não estiver.

Depois, você terá que usar o escopo transacional do Entity Framework, pois vamos fazer várias operações de banco de dados, e elas precisam ser executadas de forma atômica. Se uma delas falhar, todas devem falhar, em resumo.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AnamineseViewModel anaminese)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            Tabela2 tabela2 = anaminese.Tabela2;
            db.Tabela2.Add(anaminese.Tabela2);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Tabela3 tabela3 = anaminese.Tabela3;
            Tabela3.Tabela2 = tabela2;
            db.Tabela3.Add(tabela3);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Tabela4 tabela4 = anaminese.Tabela4;
            Tabela4.Tabela2 = tabela2;
            db.Tabela4.Add(tabela4);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Tabela5 tabela5 = anaminese.Tabela5;
            Tabela5.Tabela2 = tabela2;
            db.Tabela3.Add(tabela5);
            db.SaveChanges();

            anaminese.CliCliente.Tabela2 = tabela2;
            anaminese.CliCliente.Tabela3 = tabela3;
            anaminese.CliCliente.Tabela4 = tabela4;
            anaminese.CliCliente.Tabela5 = tabela5;
            db.CliCliente.Add(anaminese.CliCliente);
            db.SaveChanges();

            scope.Complete();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "UsuUsuario");
    }

    return View(anaminese);
}
```