# Como fazer action edit com view model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando fazer em meu projeto a parte de edição dos dados que foram cadastrados. Bem, a parte de cadastramento dos dados está funcionando bem certinha, mas agora eu preciso editar esses dados. Antes, eu andei procurando pela web para ver o que podia achar sobre isso. Achei [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334417/how-to-edit-in-asp-net-mvc-5-using-view-model) no SOus. Só que não entendi direito o código...

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente é o mesmo princípio da criação, mas alguns detalhes a mais precisam ser observados:

- O identificador do *Model* original precisa existir de alguma forma;
- Você precisará trazer do banco o *Model* duas vezes: uma para preencher o *ViewModel* e outra para atualizá-lo.

Um clichê de edição de um *Model* `Produto` com duas propriedades, `Id` e `Nome`, seria algo como:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Editar(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Produto produto = await db.Produtos.FindAsync(id);
    if (produto == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var produtoViewModel = new ProdutoViewModel 
    {
        ProdutoId = produto.ProdutoId,
        Nome = produto.Nome
    };

    return View(produtoViewModel);
}
```

A construção da sua *View* será exatamente igual como a construção usando um *Model*. O que muda é só a anotação `@model`:

```
@model MeuProjeto.ViewModels.ProdutoViewModel
```

No `POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Editar(ProdutoViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var produto = db.Produtos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProdutoId == viewModel.ProdutoId);

        if (produto == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        produto.Nome = viewModel.Nome;

        db.Entry(produto).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Vantagens da abordagem:

- Segurança: você não expõe diretamente seus *Models* em formulários;
- Flexibilidade: regras de validação mais específicas, sem necessariamente impactar o *Model*.

Desvantagens da abordagem:

- Complexidade: seu sistema ficará inevitavelmente maior e mais complexo, e a manutenção será mais difícil;
- Retrabalho: estender um *Model* significará estender todos os *ViewModels* associados ao *Model*.

Comment: Mesmo que eu tenha vários models [como nessa pergunta minha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131105/relacionamentos-n%C3%A3o-salvos), funcionaria dessa forma?

Comment: Não está dando certo. =(

Comment: Acho que é hora de outra pergunta.

Comment: Criei já a pergunta!