# Action Edit em ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Bem, estou tentando implementar a action de editar os dados de um viewmodel que possuo em meu projeto.

Até montei uma action, mas não está funcionando... O que acontece é que pelo que pesquisei, quando vai construir uma action de edit, precisa-se de referenciar o Id do model para que ele carregue os dados... O que acontece é como é ViewModel, eu não mapeio ele no banco de dados, então dessa forma eu não consigo pegar o Id.

Tenho em meu projeto várias tabelas, como digo [nessa minha pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131105/relacionamentos-n%C3%A3o-salvos), onde, para reforçar, tenho vários models que estão no ViewMOdel.

Ou seja, tenho o model CliCliente, Tabela2, Tabela3, Tabela4 e Tabela5.
Onde o CliCliente se relaciona com a Tabela2. A Tabela2 se relaciona com as outras (Tabela3, 4 e 5). Ou, para ficar mais claro, as Tabelas3, 4 e 5 se relacionam com a Tabela2.

A parte do cadastramento dos dados no sistema já está funcionando, mas agora preciso editar.... A forma como estou tentando é, mostrar o nome do cliente e a partir dele, pegar todos os outros dados. Ou seja, eu queria mostrar o nome do cliente e quando o usuário clicar em editar os dados, as informações das outras tabelas sejam carregadas para que o usuário possa editar os dados.

Tenho esses códigos:

```
// GET: Anaminese/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        CliCliente cliente = db.CliCliente.Find(id);

        if (cliente == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        AnamineseViewModel anamnese = new AnamineseViewModel();

        anamnese.CliCliente.CliId = cliente.CliId;

        return View(anamnese);
    }

    // POST: Anaminese/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(AnamineseViewModel anamneseViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(anamneseViewModel.CliCliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(anamneseViewModel.Tabeka2).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(anamneseViewModel.Tabela3).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(anamneseViewModel.Tabela4).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(anamneseViewModel.Tabela5).State = EntityState.Modified;

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        return View(anamneseViewModel);
    }
```

A view ta igual a de create, e me surgiu uma dúvida agora também... Nas views de edição já criadas pelo asp.net mvc ao fazer o scaffolding, tem um campo hidden que pega o Id do dado que quer editar, no ViewModel, precisa também?

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar? Pois já esta dando erro no GET e eu não sei como resolver!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A meu ver, acho que você não entendeu coisa alguma das explicações.

Isto não vai funcionar:

```
AnamineseViewModel anamnese = new AnamineseViewModel();

anamnese.CliCliente.CliId = cliente.CliId;
```

`CliCliente` será `null`, muito provavelmente. Nada no seu código mostra que `CliCliente` será instanciado. O correto seria:

```
AnamineseViewModel anamnese = new AnamineseViewModel 
{
    CliCliente = cliente
};
```

> Nas views de edição já criadas pelo asp.net mvc ao fazer o scaffolding, tem um campo hidden que pega o Id do dado que quer editar, no ViewModel, precisa também?

Naturalmente que sim, porque você está fazendo isto:

```
db.Entry(anamneseViewModel.CliCliente).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(anamneseViewModel.Tabela2).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(anamneseViewModel.Tabela3).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(anamneseViewModel.Tabela4).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.Entry(anamneseViewModel.Tabela5).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Sem o Id correspondente de cada entidade, nenhum desses comandos irá funcionar.

Comment: pergunta: onde tem `CliCliente = cliente` onde `cliente` é que pega o Id do cliente, referenciado na assinatura da action (`int? id`), eu poderia usar para todas as minhas views esse `id`?

Comment: Não entendi nada do que você disse. `cliente` vem de `CliCliente cliente = db.CliCliente.Find(id);`. O que você quer dizer com "eu poderia usar para todas as minhas Views"?

Comment: Já resolvi aqui essa parte... Agora to com outro problema... É que nos models tenho dois que são listas.. Precisava saber uma forma de pegar esses valores da lista

Comment: Basicamente usando BeginCollectionItem. [Veja algumas respostas aqui sobre como usar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+begincollectionitem).

Answer (score -1):

Tenta isso:

```
    [HttpGet]        
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {           

        CliCliente cliente = db.x*.Find(id);
        if (cliente == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

    AnamineseViewModel anamnese = new AnamineseViewModel();

    anamnese = cliente.CliCliente.CliId;

    return View(anamnese);

    }
```

**Obs:** Nesse "x*" você tem que por o DbSet de CliCliente no DbContext algo como 'public DbSet<"CliCliente"> (sem as aspas) clientes { get; set;}' caso fosse dessa maneira você colocaria 'db.clientes.Find(id)'

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(AnamineseViewModel model) //mudei para model para você não se confundir com o Model.AnamineseViewModel
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(model.CliCliente).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(model.Tabela2).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(model.Tabela3).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(model.Tabela4).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(model.Tabela5).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }

    return View(anamneseViewModel);
}
```

Talvez o erro esteja ocorrendo por você estar tentando alterar a database sem por System.Data.Entity antes do EntityState