# Como retornar valores de duas tabelas distintas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou trabalhando em um script de *auto complete* que deverá efetuar uma busca em duas tabelas de mesmo nível (Cursos e Pacotes) (sem relação) e retornar os valores mesclados em uma única lista. O problema é que a *query* abaixo não está retornando nenhum valor:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Autocomplete(Entities db, string search)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var query = from c in db.courses.Where(c => c.title.Contains(search))
                from p in db.packages.Where(p => p.title.Contains(search))
                select new { c, p };

    return Json(query.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Mas quando a busca é feita de forma individual os dados são retornados normalmente:

```
var query = from c in db.courses.Where(c => c.title.Contains(search))
            select new { c };
```

Preciso que os valores relacionados a busca seja retornado de ambas as tabelas ao mesmo tempo, ou que seja feita buscas individuais mas que sejam mesclados depois.

Como posso resolver?

Comment: se você fizer a query var query = from c in db.courses.Where(c => c.title.Contains(search))  select new { c }; ela retorna alguma coisa?

Comment: Sim, retorna quando a busca é feita individualmente.

Comment: Sem o `Where` funciona?

Comment: Buscando individualmente sim, buscando nas duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo não.

Comment: E buscando nas duas tabelas sem a cláusula where?

Comment: Dá erro: "Foi detectada uma referência circular ao serializar um objeto do tipo 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.courses_F2EBA347335381B70B698E71131F0692220242D0763A30FAB52385A661639DFF'"

Comment: Tem como você colocar o código dos Models? Pelo menos as propriedades deles.

Comment: Você quer que cada linha da tabela Cursos tenha uma linha mesclada da tabela Pacotes? você já verificou quantas linhas cada uma delas retorna quando feito independentes?

Comment: É Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para retornar somente em uma lista pode se usar o método [concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

**Cenário 1:**

Tenho duas entidades: `courses` e `packages`, sendo que:

- `courses` tem três campos (*id, title e status*) e;
- `packages` tem dois campos (*id e title*).

Precisa normalizar então, colocando a mesma quantidade de campos na entidade `packages` e também observar o tipo do campo para que não tenha erros de  conversão. Foi colocado o tipo `bool?` porque o campo `status` de `courses` é desse tipo; Como pegar o tipo de campo: `é só olhar na entidade mapeado o seu tipo`

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
{

    var courses = db.Cours.Select(c => new
    {
        c.Id, 
        c.Title, 
        c.Status
    });

    var packages = db.Packages.Select(c => new 
    {
        c.Id, 
        c.Title, 
        Status = new bool?()
    });

    var js = courses.Concat(packages);
    var items = js.ToList();

}
```

**Cenário 2:**

Eu quero pegar o mesmo tanto de campos das entidades e eles são iguais, por exemplo *id e nome*, como seria:

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
{

    var courses = db.Cours.Select(c => new
    {
        c.Id, 
        c.Title
    });

    var packages = db.Packages.Select(c => new 
    {
        c.Id, 
        c.Title
    });

    var js = courses.Concat(packages);
    var items = js.ToList();

}
```

---

**Observação:** os dois cenários quem resolve é a parte SQL do banco, não havendo baixa no desempenho.

***No seu código***:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Autocomplete(Entities db, string search)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var courses = db.Courses.Select(c => new
    {
        c.Id,
        c.Title
    });

    var packages = db.Packages.Select(c => new
    {
        c.Id,
        c.Title
    });

    var js = courses.Concat(packages);

    return Json(js.Where(c => c.Title
                  .Contains(search))
                  .ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

***Exemplo Site Microsoft:***

[Concatenate Two Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386979%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
IQueryable<String> custQuery =
    (from cust in db.Customers
    select cust.Phone)
    .Concat
    (from cust in db.Customers
    select cust.Fax)
    .Concat
    (from emp in db.Employees
    select emp.HomePhone);

foreach (var custData in custQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(custData);
}
```

*Esse exemplo ilustra muito bem que os tipos dos campos devem ser do mesmo tipo independente do nome do campo (apesar que pode ser feito o alias, para um boa leitura de código) e na mesma ordem.*

Answer (score 3):

Existem algumas formas de se fazer isso, uma delas é retornar os resultados por meio de uma lista dinâmica.

Ficaria algo parecido com isso:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Autocomplete(Entities db, string search)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    return Json(new { 
                  couses = db.courses.Where(c => c.title.Contains(search)).ToList(),
                  packages = db.packages.Where(p => p.title.Contains(search)).ToList()
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Assim você irá ter um retorno parecido com isso:

```
{
  "couses": [
    {
      //Lista de courses
    }
  ],
  "packages": [
    {
      //Lista de Packages
    }
  ],
}
```

Ou também pode criar uma [ViewModel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130773/20615), deixando tudo tipado e organizado.

Mas, se uma tabela não tem relação com a outra, eu não tentaria englobar tudo no mesmo `select`, senão depois vira uma bagunça e de difícil manutenção.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `SelectMany` para mesclados  seus valores, só a uma questão isso seria para um caso onde `db.packages.Where(p => p.title.Contains(search)`, seja comparado com uma variável do `db.courses.Where(c => c.title`, mas como você não passou o modelo ficar difícil de criar uma solução melhor, mas da forma que esta acredito que resolva.

```
    var query = db.courses.Where(c => c.title.Contains(search)
      .SelectMany(C => db.packages.Where(p => p.title.Contains(search).DefaultIfEmpty()
      , (n, a) => new
            { n, a }
      );
```

[Veja a referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958949/difference-between-select-and-selectmany).