# Lista Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou criado a *action* de *Edit* para editar os dados dos meus *models*. O que acontece é que uso *ViewModel* para "juntar" vários *models* em um.

Ok, eu consigo pegar os dados de *models* que não são `List<>`, ou seja, os *models* que não estão uma lista. O meu caso é que tenho listas e precisava pegar todos os registros referentes ao `id` que estou passando na assinatura da *Action* para que os dados possam ser carregados na tela, e e editar esses dados.

O código que tenho é esse aqui:

```
 CliCliente cliente = db.CliCliente.Find(id);
 Tabela2 tabela2 = db.Tabela2.Find(id);
 Tabela3 tabela3 = db.Tabela3.Find(id);

 List<Tabela4> tabela4 = db.Tabela4.ToList<Tabela4>();
```

Em que `List<Tabela4> tabela4 = db.Tabela4.ToList<Tabela4>();` me retorna todos os dados, porque não tenho um critério para retornar somente o que está relacionado no `id` que estou trazendo na *action*.

Como que eu poderia fazer para varrer e trazer os dados da lista especificos relacionados ao `id` enviado na assinatura da *action*?

Comment: Se o `id` é de `CliCliente` e `Tabela2`, `Tabela3` e `Tabela4` estão relacionados, por que você não seleciona apenas de `CliCliente` e usa apenas `Include()`s para carregar os dados agregados?

Comment: Eu tentei, mas não consegui... E dessa forma com o include sairia uma lista? Porque preciso retornar uma lista...

Comment: Retornar para onde?

Comment: para a view... E tambem no controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aqui você disse como são os relacionamentos entre suas tabelas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130770/como-funciona-o-viewmodel-no-asp-net-mvc). Supondo isso, posso fazer o seguinte:

```
CliCliente cliente = db.CliCliente
                       .Include(c => c.Tabela2)
                       .Include(c => c.Tabela3)
                       .Include(c => c.Tabela4)
                       .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CliClienteId == id);

return View(cliente);
```

Sua *View*:

```
@model SeuProjeto.Models.CliCliente

@foreach (var elemento in Model.Tabela4)
{
    <p>@elemento.Nome</p>
}
```