# Como usar 4 model em uma view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Olá, tenho 4 *class* `Cliente`, `Locacao`, `Item` e `Cacamba`:

```
public class Cliente
{
  public Guid ClienteID { get; set; }
  public string Nome { get; set; }
  ...............
}

public class Locacao
{
   public Guid LocacaoID { get; set;}
   public Guid ClienteID {get;set;}
   public DateTime DataLocacao { get; set; }
   public DateTime DataEntrega { get; set; }
   public string Endereco { get; set; }
   ........
}

public class Item
{
    public Guid ItemID {get;set;}
    public Guid LocacaoID {get;set;}
    public Guid CaçambaID {get;set;}
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
}

public class Cacamba    
{
       public Guid CacambaID{get;set;}
       public string NomeCacamba {get;set;}
       public string Descricao {get;set;}
       public decimal Preco {get;set;}
       ............
 }
```

Que eu queria, se for possível, é poder fazer em apenas uma página, onde eu carrego todos os clientes e seleciono o cliente, depois preencho os dados da locação, depois seleciono a caçamba e já jogue diretamente em uma tabela o ID da caçamba, o nome, o preço e o valor total, na própria pagina, e no final eu salve os dados que tem na `Locacao` e no `Item` no banco.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem duas opções (mais indicadas) para fazer isso.

### 1º Faça por relacionamentos.

Todos os seus `Models` são relacionados, dessa forma você consegue obter as propriedades dos outros apenas "navegando" entre eles. Seria algo como:

**Locacao.cs**

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cliente.Nome)
```

Essa é a forma normal, sem precisar criar nada. Lembrando que se deseja salvar uma lista de dados, ou selecionar um item em um `DropDown`, deve adaptar ao seu modelo.

### 2º Faça por ViewModel

Você pode criar uma `ViewModel` e colocar os items nela. Não há necessidade, visto que os mesmos são relacionados entre si, mas é uma opção válida também. Ficaria algo parecido com isso:

**ClienteViewModel.cs**

```
var clienteViewModel = new ClienteViewModel{
    Cliente = New Cliente(),//preencha o cliente aqui
    Locacao = New Locacao(),
    Item = new Item(),
    Cacamba = new Cacamba()
};

return View(clienteViewModel);
```

Qualquer uma dessas formas irá resolver seu problema. Mas dependendo do que realmente quiser realizar, terá que ser adequado à sua `View`.

[Esta resposta está mais detalhada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130773/20615), aconselho a olhar para entender melhor o que expliquei.